# ASP.NET MVC filter for all Exceptions (included already handled)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, c#-3.0

ASP.NET  MVC: is there a filter to know when a controller enters in a catch block? OnException is not working based on the fact that it is just 4 unhandled ex.

Comment: Not unless you re-throw the exception from within the catch block.

Answer (score 0):

You can write your own attribute derived from **ActionFilterAttribute**

```
public class LogExceptionAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
    {
        public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
        {
                base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
        }

        public override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
        {
                //here you can inspect filterContext for exceptions
                base.OnActionExecuted(filterContext);
        }

        public override void OnResultExecuting(ResultExecutingContext filterContext)
        {
            base.OnResultExecuting(filterContext);
        }

        public override void OnResultExecuted(ResultExecutedContext filterContext)
        {
            base.OnResultExecuted(filterContext);
        }
    }
```

And then put the attribute on the action/controller or register it in the **Global.asax**, `ApplicationStart()` as the global filter.

**Example:**

```
 [LogException]
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            throw new Exception();
            return View();
        }
```

[image]

That will enable you to log the exception or do something else.

Comment: it just works for the unhandled exceptions (I should rethrow the exception in order this to work).